# Python: Find the numbers for which the sum of the digits raised by the power of the number of digits in a number is equal to the number itself

Tags: python, math, logic

> Find the numbers for which the sum of the digits raised by the power
> of the number of digits in a number is equal to the number itself.

For example

```
 2^1 = 2
 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153
 3^3 + 7^3 + 0^3 = 370
 1^4 + 6^4 + 3^4 + 4^4 = 1634
```

Wrote the following code:

```
armstrong_num=[]
for i in range(0, 10000):
    n=len(i)
    total=0
    for j in i:
        total = total+(j)**n
        if total==int(i):
            armstrong_num.append()
print(armstrong_num)
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '153', '370', '370', '371', '407', '1634', '6688', '8208', '9474']
```

It works fine except one problem. The number 370 is identified twice. Any hint to correct the code.

Comment: Make `armstrong_num` a set instead of a list?

Comment: At any rate, your code doesn't run. `n = len(i)` doesn't make sense, as `i` is an `int`, and doesn't have a length.

Comment: The code is full of errors, which the python interpreter will alert you to. The code you posted *does not* do what you say it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below accounts for a few of the comments left on your post.  ** Updated accounting for @Mark's comment posted below.

```
armstrong_num=[]
for i in range(0, 10000):
    n=len(str(i))
    total=0
    for char in str(i):
        total = total+(int(char))**n
    if total==int(i):
       armstrong_num.append(i)
print(armstrong_num)
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark!! I updated the post above.  Good catch!

Comment: Thanks again, @Mark. I have Grammarly running so I must have accepted the fix by accident.